# Poisson model and 0 degrees of freedom for residual deviance

Tags: r, statistics

I am investigating a count data set using the poisson model in R. Curiously I obtained results where there are 0 degrees of freedom for residual deviance, could someone explain this? Is it a problem with my coding? I am new to R, so I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
> mod.fit.poi<-glm(formula = count ~ variable*Carbon, family = poisson(link = "log"), data = melted)
> summary(mod.fit.poi)

Call:
glm(formula = count ~ variable * Carbon, family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = melted)

Deviance Residuals: 
  [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [30]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [59]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [88]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                     3.332e+00  1.890e-01  17.632  < 2e-16 ***
variableForestTundra            4.964e-01  2.397e-01   2.071 0.038347 *  
variableTundra                  6.568e-01  2.329e-01   2.820 0.004799 ** 
CarbonC11                      -1.723e+00  4.855e-01  -3.548 0.000388 ***
CarbonC9                       -1.386e+00  4.226e-01  -3.281 0.001036 **
```

etc...

```
variableForestTundra:CarbonC11  1.072e+00  5.469e-01   1.960 0.049949 *
```

etc....

```
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2.4187e+03  on 104  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 5.5790e-10  on   0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 681.69

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 22
```

Comment: Description of `Carbon` and `variable`?

Comment: Your model fits 105 parameters to 105 observations.